# The probability measure of intersection

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a probability space and $(A_n)$ a sequence of sets in $\mathcal{F}$. If $\mu(A_n) \rightarrow 1$, then for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a subsequence $(n_k)$ such that
$$\mu(\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{n_k}) \geq 1-\varepsilon$$

I know that by Fatou's lemma, $\mu(\text{limsup}A_n)=1$ and $\lim_n\mu(A_n)=\mu(\lim_nA_n)=1$, by the continuity of probability. Since $\mu(A_n) \rightarrow 1$, $\exists N: \forall n \geq N, \mu(A_n)>1-\varepsilon$. But I don't know how to show the above result.

Answer (score 1):

Choose an increasing sequence  $n_k$ such that $\mu (A_{n_k}) >1-\epsilon /2^{k}$. Then $\mu(A_{n_k}^{c}) < \epsilon /2^{k}$ and $\mu(\bigcup_k A_{n_k}^{c}) <\sum_k\epsilon /2^{k}=\epsilon$. This gives   $\mu(\bigcap_k A_{n_k})>1-\epsilon$.